# Use breaklines without arrows

Tags: listings, line-breaking, arrows, minted

I use `breaklines` to get automatic breaks (if I don't do this, my text goes over the right edge).

But I want to get rid of those arrows after every break. Is this possible?

```
    \documentclass{article}
     \usepackage{listings}
     \usepackage{minted}
     \begin{document}
     \begin{minted}[breaklines,obeytabs=true,tabsize=2]{bash}
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
     \end{minted}
     \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the option `breaksymbolleft` to control the symbol inserted at the left after line breaks. Using e.g. in your example

```
\begin{minted}[breaklines,obeytabs=true,tabsize=2,breaksymbolleft=]{bash}
```

will remove the harpoon and the indentation.

See the [documention of `minted`](http://mirror.unl.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/minted/minted.pdf) for further information. The explanation of the option `breaklines` discusses the possibilities for influencing the line break, listing options like `breaksymbolleft`, `breaksymbolleft`, `breaksymbolsepleft`, `breaksymbolsepleft`, `breakindent`, `breakautoindent`, and several more.

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect! I will read the documention next time.